# Spring Security - Session is timed out if the user is active on a page

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I have used Spring security and i am facing problem mentioned below  :
For my Web Application : in my web. x ml file ,session timeout is mentioned as 
     
    30

But if the user is active how do i stop session from being timed out.
The Session automatically timed out whether the user is active on a page or not.
How to achieve this in Spring security?

Comment: What does it mean to be "active on a page"? Is there any activity towards the server?

Answer (score 0):

it can not be handled unti the browser connect to server after session time out .
U can use a timer js function connect to server every seconds.

Comment: if i use timer js then how will i make the session not to expire...as if user is active on a page then how will the timer js help in not timing out the session. as that is being handled in web xml file